# Adding data to highcharts(Highstock) when user scrolling reaches left end

Tags: javascript, svg, highcharts

I'm using [highstock](http://highcharts.com/products/highstock) on my website. The scroll bar in the navigator of stock chart is drawn using SVG. I want to add more data(via ajax) to the graph when user scrolls to the leftmost end.

I am new to SVG and not sure how to detect that user has scrolled to the end and fire a ajax query based on that. Can anyone help me with this.

Thanks,
Sivakumar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, today I had the same problem, and I just found your question.

I don't know if you have any reason for loading the new data only when the user moves the scrollbar, I would recommend to fire the ajax query if the user visualizes the left-most data, instead (that is: scrolling the bar, pressing the left arrow, dragging the area of the navigation chart, and so on).

If this solution applies to you, you can try with something like this:

```
chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'chart',
            events: {
                redraw: function(event) {
                    if (chart.xAxis) {
                        var extremes = chart.xAxis[0].getExtremes();
                        if (extremes && extremes.min == extremes.dataMin) {
                            console.log("time to load more data!");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }, [...]
```

Comment: Not working properly..! I was trying to impliment scroll till end using button click.

Comment: for the code to work the condition must be extremes.min <= extremes.dataMin

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem in the following way.

```
<script>

import axios from 'axios';

export default {
    name: 'Chart',
    data() {
        return {
            chartOptions: {
                chart: {
                    events: {
                        // we will lose the context of the component if we define a function here
                    }
                },
                series: [{
                    type: 'candlestick',
                    data: null,
                }],
            },
        };
    },
    methods: {
        onRedraw: function () {
            let chart = this.$refs.chart.chart
            if (chart.xAxis) {
                let extremes = chart.xAxis[0].getExtremes()
                console.log(extremes)
                if (extremes && extremes.min <= extremes.dataMin) {
                    console.log("time to load more data!");
                }
            }
        }

    },
    created() {
        axios.get('https://demo-live-data.highcharts.com/aapl-ohlcv.json').then((response) => {
            this.chartOptions.series[0].data = response.data
            this.chartOptions.series[0].name = 'AAPL'
        });
        
        this.chartOptions.chart.events.redraw = this.onRedraw
    },
};
</script>

<template>
  <highcharts :constructor-type="'stockChart'" :options="chartOptions" ref="chart"></highcharts>
</template>
```